# wordpress / WooCommerce customize product plugin for Jewelry

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, woocommerce, js-fancyproductdesigner

Is there a plugin that could print customer's name on necklace. I've tried **Fancy Product** plugin which is good for customizing t shirts and mugs but unable to find anything that could print the name on jewelry mostly known as **name necklace**
there are many websites selling such products using this feature

for example 
https://www.jewlr.com/products/JWLN0327/10k-yellow-gold-infinite-love-name-necklace?sku=10KY&ch=&e1=Noman&e2=Nasir

Comment: Can you please update which plugin you have used for customizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer and passed by accident but I do know a Customizing plugin that can do any custom work exactly how you are describing and works with a bunch of items ( I found it when looking for custom engraving for tombstones )

Try Zakeke
https://www.zakeke.com/

You do have to use their own site to customize exactly where you want to do the edits which is a downside for me, hate jumping between sites..

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what i needed